# Add force without direction

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to add force to an object without declaring it's direction.
I want to throw the ball but I just need to add  force once touch on release.
I used this code `rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * 20;` but  the ball changed it direction and moved forward after the ball follow the direction intended by the user on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood, you want to apply the force (or maybe an impulse?) in the direction of where the ball is going, i.e., in direction of its velocity:

```
Vector3 forceDirection = transform.velocity * 20;
currentGameObject.rigidbody.AddForce(forceDirection, ForceMode.Impulse); // or ForceMode.Force
```

I didn't understand very well, I mean, the force must have a direction, right? I'm assuming you want it to go where it's already going.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Rigidbody.AddForce](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html) and play with the different [ForceModes](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html). If I understand you right, Impulse or VelocityChange will fit your needs.

```
Vector3 forceDirection = transform.forward * 20;
currentGameObject.rigidbody.AddForce(forceDirection, ForceMode.Force);
```

Comment: It seems that your codes behavior will be likely the same which I posted.The problem is when I tried to throw or roll a ball it always follows same path.ex. if first ball thrown at middle and travels and landed on the center all the ball will acted that way.because there are using same script.what I want if I drag the ball to left then try to roll the ball then the ball will roll it should moved forward straight from its position. or the best thing is it follows the direction of movement of the finger best example will be is a flick kick starter.